How to remove dynamic field from mapping with Elastic Reindex API
We have a dynamic field defined in multiple indexes that is of type geo_shape, and uses the points_only param. Due to a) the deprecation of points_only in version 7.x, and b) the fact that we don't use that field any more, we want to remove it from the mapping and the data, although the mapping is the most important, since we don't search on that field.
First, here is the mapping definition:
"mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
        {
            "base_geo": {
                "match": "*Geo",
                "mapping": {
                    "points_only": true,
                    "type": "geo_shape"
                }
            }
        },
    ...
    ]
}

It appears that the Reindex API can be used to do this, since in order to remove a field from a mapping, a new index has to be created. As such, I've been trying variations on this to POST _reindex
{
    "source": {
        "index": "local_federal_agency_models_1708127195"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "local_federal_agency_models_1708127195_3"
    },
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.remove('base_geo')"
    }
}

However, this not only removes the base_geo field, but it removes the entire dynamic_templates array, so it removes all dynamic mappings.
As for the documents themselves, I know I can use an ingest pipeline, but how can I just remove my base_geo field mapping when re-indexing?

Can u show mapping for new index? GET /local_federal_agency_models_1708127195/_mapping

As per the documentation, _reindex API don't copy the settings, mappings, dynamic_templates etc. Below is what mentioned in this documentation.

Reindex requires _source to be enabled for all documents in the
source.
The destination should be configured as wanted before calling
_reindex. Reindex does not copy the settings from the source or its associated template.
Mappings, shard counts, replicas, and so on must be configured ahead
of time.

Hence, first you need to create new index with settings, mapping, dynamic_templates as require and then copy the data.
You can use below command to get existing index mapping:
GET local_federal_agency_models_1708127195

After that, you can use same output and create index using PUT
PUT local_federal_agency_models_1708127195_3
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
        {
            //your configuration
        },
    ...
    ]
}
}

then finally, you can run _reindex API.
{
    "source": {
        "index": "local_federal_agency_models_1708127195"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "local_federal_agency_models_1708127195_3"
    },
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.remove('base_geo')"
    }
}

Regarding your below statement, you must first remove the data then only you can remove the field from the index mapping, otherwise it will not allow to delete field from the mapping.

the fact that we don't use that field any more, we want to remove it
from the mapping and the data, although the mapping is the most
important, since we don't search on that field.

